# error writing variable name containing other variable in smarty3 while using custom delimiter

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

in Smarty3 we can write variable name containing other variable

for example

```
<?php
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->assign("x",1);
$smarty->assign("foo_1","aka");
$smarty->template_dir = "./";
$smarty->display("tpl.tpl");
```

file *./tpl.tpl* content:

```
{$foo_{$x}}              
<!-- will output aka because foo_1 is assigned as aka -->
```

and until now sounds good , but if we use custom delimiter , smarty engine stop writing variables containing other variable

for example if we use <--[ as left delimiter and ]--> as right delimiter

example

```
<?php
 $smarty = new Smarty;
 $smarty->left_delimiter = '<--[';
 $smarty->right_delimiter = ']-->';
 $smarty->assign("x",1);
 $smarty->assign("foo_1","aka");
 $smarty->template_dir = "./";
 $smarty->display("tpl.tpl");
```

and when the ./tpl.tpl file  contain

```
<--[$foo_<--[$x]-->]-->
```

an error return with

**Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template ".\tpl.tpl" on line 1 "<--[$foo_<--[$x]-->]-->" - Unexpected "--" <-- thrown in E:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\vac\source\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 1**

any advices?

Comment: It looks like your setting the delimiters as braces instead of brackets.

Comment: smarty allow us to use custom delimiters evev braces @see http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/variable.left.delimiter.tpl

Comment: @MohammedShannaq but you should edit your question in one place you have `<--{` delimiter and in the other `<--[`

Comment: @jkushner sorry, I edit it

Comment: Hi i removed my answer, because i didn't understand you problem correctly. I think your var access is unusual. Have you considered, to use a array-variables? Have you tried: <--[$foo_$x]--> ? if you are using a - it will result in a math expression <- minus -->

Comment: @BerndOtt I found the answer and I'm writing it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search and lot of headache I found the solution

take a look to this smarty modifier plugin http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=VarVar

it was written for Smarty2 , I just modify it to serv for Smarty3

and the solve of my question was

```
<?php
$smarty = new Smarty;
function smarty_modifier_varvar($string) {
    global $smarty;
    if (empty($string)) {
        return;
    }
    $array = explode(".", $string);
    $var = array_shift($array);
    $val = $smarty->tpl_vars[$var]->value;        
    if (count($array) == 0) {
        return $val;
    } else {
        $idx = "['" . join("']['", $array) . "']";
        eval("\$return = \$val$idx;");
        return $return;
    }
}




$smarty->left_delimiter = '<--[';
$smarty->right_delimiter = ']-->';    
$smarty->assign("x",1);
$smarty->assign("foo_1","aka");
$smarty->template_dir = "./";
$smarty->display("tpl.tpl");
```

and the *./tpl.tpl* file was

```
<--["foo_$x"|varvar]-->
```

and the output was
    aka
becuse **$foo_1** is assigned as *aka*

Comment: And why exactly you use custom delimiters? It makes templates less portable and harder to understand by other developers. I would not recommend it unless you have very strong reason to do that

Comment: I used custom delimiters to avoid collision with other javascript and css without need to use literal

Comment: Have you read this: `{literal}{/literal} tags are normally not necessary, as Smarty ignores delimiters that are surrounded by whitespace. Be sure your javascript and CSS curly braces are surrounded by whitespace. This is new behavior to Smarty 3. ` ?

Comment: some minified javasscript files that I uses with smarty have {} without witespaces. coz I use smarty to fetch javascript files with getjs.php. but thank you I will consider using {} for delimiters in next projects.